# Raster statistics per latitude cross-section

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, spatial-statistics

I want a profile graph with biomass volume across a landscape's latitude. Im using ArcGis Pro 2.3.3. It's hard to explain so I'll provide a rough sketch of the desired result:

[image]

The sketch shows a polygon (placeholder), but I will use a raster with biomass per hectare instead. Every point on the x-axis should represent the mean of biomass per hectare for that corresponding cross-section on the map. I've been playing around with summary statistics but it won't do the job.

Do I have to divide the raster into cross-section and run summary statistics on them separately or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have 3D analyst extension? Then maybe something like this is possible [Creating a profile graph from digitized features of a Surface](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/creating-a-profile-graph-from-digitized-features-of-a-surface.htm).

Comment: Why don't you convert your raster to a point dataset add your lat/long coordinates and then do a simple summary on that? Group by latitude and mean the gridcode. The output could then be plotted in something like excel?

Comment: @Hornbydd Thanks a lot, I didn't think about that at all. Solved my problem!